# My Intel i7 12700k doesn't support intel VT-x

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, intel, bios, vt-x

I'm trying to run a virtualmachine on my new laptop Intel i7 12700k and I get the error telling me that the VT-X is not enabled. I have been able to install virtualbox but nothing can be install on it. I've activated the VT Technonlogy from BIOS and I still get the error. Is there a way to fix that error. My laptop run windows 11 Home.

Another guy posted the error on edit and here is the question:
I just built a PC with the Asus Z690-F motherboard and an Intel Core i7 12700k and I need to do some virtualization with VT-x. I look in bios to see if its just disabled but all that is there is VT-d. I updated the BIOS too but its still not there. I then downloaded this software that tells me whether the CPU supports VT-x, and it says it doesn't. I'm confused because the intel site says the i7 12700k supports VT-x hardware virtualization. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I've run the command

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```